XGBoost Classifier, Grid search
I am trying to apply an XGBoost Classifier model in Python via XGBClassifier (see documentation here). The idea is to train the model on a city-year (e.g. zurich-2000) couple and test it on data for the same city in year+5 (e.g. zurich-2005). I am doing this for a set of cities and for the 5 year couples (2000,2005); (2001,2006);...;(2008,2013). The idea is to learn, via a Grid search, the hyperparameters that minimize a classification loss when, we use the model trained in year t to make predictions in year t+5 (using as tst features the feature in year t+5). The code I have made for the moment looks as follows.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, f1_score, matthews_corrcoef
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, train_test_split
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

# Assume top_50_cities_per_city_df is defined somewhere
# top_50_cities_per_city_df = ...

years = range(2000, 2009)
cities = top_50_cities_per_city_df.columns

results = []
best_params = []

# Step 1: Hyperparameter tuning with reduced parameter grid and parallel processing
param_grid = {
    'max_depth': [3, 6, 9],
    'learning_rate': [0.01, 0.1, 0.2],
    'n_estimators': [50, 100, 200]
}

def tune_hyperparameters(city, start_year, end_year):
    try:
        ####### USE THIS FOR LOUVAIN
        #file_path_start = f"/Users/federiconutarelli/Desktop/paper_revisions/smart_cities/MC_cluster/MC_w_clusters/thresholded_data/{city}{start_year}.csv"
        #file_path_end = f"/Users/federiconutarelli/Desktop/paper_revisions/smart_cities/MC_cluster/MC_w_clusters/thresholded_data/{city}{end_year}.csv"

        ####### USE THIS FOR MM
        #file_path_start = f"/Users/federiconutarelli/Desktop/paper_revisions/smart_cities/MC_cluster/MC_w_clusters/MM_clustering/thresholded_data_MM/{city}{start_year}.csv"
        #file_path_end = f"/Users/federiconutarelli/Desktop/paper_revisions/smart_cities/MC_cluster/MC_w_clusters/MM_clustering/thresholded_data_MM/{city}{end_year}.csv"

         ####### USE THIS FOR PSBM
        file_path_start = f"/Users/federiconutarelli/Desktop/paper_revisions/smart_cities/MC_cluster/MC_w_clusters/SBM_clustering/thresholded_data_PSBM/{city}{start_year}.csv"
        file_path_end = f"/Users/federiconutarelli/Desktop/paper_revisions/smart_cities/MC_cluster/MC_w_clusters/SBM_clustering/thresholded_data_PSBM/{city}{end_year}.csv"

        df_start = pd.read_csv(file_path_start, header=None)
        df_end = pd.read_csv(file_path_end, header=None)
        
        new_column_names_start = [f'IPC{i+1}' for i in range(len(df_start.columns))]
        new_column_names_end = [f'IPC{i+1}' for i in range(len(df_end.columns))]
        
        df_start.columns = new_column_names_start
        df_end.columns = new_column_names_end
        
        df_train = df_start.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x > 0 else (0 if x < 0 else 0))
        df_test = df_end.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x > 0 else (0 if x < 0 else 0))
        
        X = df_train.T.values[:, 1:50]
        Y = df_train.T.values[:, 0]

        features_test = df_test.T.values[:, 1:50] 
        seed = 7
        test_size = 0.33
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=test_size, random_state=seed)
        
        # Hyperparameter tuning
        model = XGBClassifier(use_label_encoder=False, eval_metric='mlogloss')
        grid_search = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid, cv=3, scoring='f1_weighted', n_jobs=-1)
        grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
        
        best_param = grid_search.best_params_
        best_params.append(best_param)
        
        # Predict on test data with best parameters
        model = XGBClassifier(**best_param, use_label_encoder=False, eval_metric='mlogloss')
        model.fit(X_train, y_train)
        y_pred = model.predict(features_test)
        
        # Evaluate predictions
        y_true = df_test.T.values[:, 0]
        accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
        precision = precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='weighted')
        f1 = f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='weighted')
        matthews = matthews_corrcoef(y_true, y_pred)
        
        # Save results
        result = {
            'city': city,
            'start_year': start_year,
            'end_year': end_year,
            'accuracy': accuracy,
            'precision': precision,
            'f1_score': f1,
            'matthews_corrcoef': matthews
        }
        
        print(f"Processed {city} for years {start_year} and {end_year}")
        return result, best_params
    
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"File not found for {city} in years {start_year} or {end_year}. Skipping...")
        return None
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred for {city} in years {start_year} and {end_year}: {e}")
        return None

results = Parallel(n_jobs=-1, verbose=10)(delayed(tune_hyperparameters)(city, start_year, start_year + 5) for start_year in years for city in cities)

# Filter out None results
results = [result for result in results if result is not None]

My questions, since the prediction scores are not the best:

Am I using the correct metric for the loss?
Is there a cv method for XGBoost classifier which would perform better than a manually constructed grid search?
In general do you think that the logic of my code reflects what I tried to explain at the top of the section?

